# Django OneToOne field - no reverse accessor to AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, model, relation

I am trying to extend Django's default UserModel, referenced by settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, with a custom model, UserProfile.
In every case I use the OneToOne-Relationship, I get an accessor on the referenced model also. So this usually works:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
   link_to_model_a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


model_a = ModelA()
model_a.modelb  # Works fine
```

But it does not work in this case (snippet shortened):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # There are more fields, but removed
    # for this example

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
get_user_model().userprofile # Causes AttributeError: type object 'User" has no attribute 'userprofile'
```

I could not find any information about if this phenomenon could appear due to the relationship to djangos default user-model. Maybe they treat it in a special way and do not allow reverse accessing?

I'm really thankful for any help in this concern.

Comment: did you ran migrations?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution on my own.

In this case, I split up my models in seperate files. I used a __ init __.py file in my /models/ directory, but did not explicitly import all my models in __ init __.py.

After doing so, Django could find my OneToOne-connection from UserProfile to its User-model and everything works fine.

Thank you all for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is, `get_user_model()` returns the class `User` not `User()`. So, you could not access `userprofile`.

It is trying to access the static attribute present in `User` with name `userprofile`.

Comment: Thank you for your help; unfortunately there is no such reverse accessor also. This is the weird thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding directly the relation yo `YourCustomUserModel` in case you are using a specific one, if not you can just add the `User` model:

```
from my_app import YourCustomUserModel

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # There are more fields, but removed
    # for this example

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        YourCustomUserModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

If using the default user model you can go with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  # check this line

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # There are more fields, but removed
    # for this example

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,  # check this line
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

And because you will not be changing your user `AUTH_USER_MODEL` so much (or never) you will not have any problema bout that, just remember change it here too if by any chance you have to use another one.

Comment: Thank your for your help. Unfortunately no reverse accessor appears with this solution.